# Converting using ImageMagick creates 2 images of the same

Tags: imagemagick

I'm converting images into different sizes using ImageMagick. The conversion works OK, but there are some files that are converted twice.

For example, i'm converting a filename `rj54c124a4cb96b3.56843124.tif` into jpg using the suffix `small`.

The conversion works OK but i'm getting two of the same, like so: `rj54c124a4cb96b3.56843124_small-0.jpg` and `rj54c124a4cb96b3.56843124_small-1.jpg`

It adds a number after the suffix! Why? Like i've said, out of 3000 files, it only does that to a couple.

**EDIT:**

As per Keith Thompson question, here's the script im using in PHP

```
$file = 'c:/website_gallery/rj54c124a4cb96b3.56843124.tif';
$output = 'c:/public_html/gallery/files/4/2/rj54c124a4cb96b3.56843124_small.jpg';
$operator = '-resize'; // in some cases i will use -thumbnail
$width = 125;
$height = 125;
$flag = '^>'; // for localhost; use \> for live host server

exec('convert' . ' ' . $file . ' ' . $operator . ' ' . $width . 'x' . $height . $flag . ' ' . $output, $debug, $return);
```

Comment: How exactly are you converting the files? If you're using the shell commands, this probably isn't a programming question (unless you're looking for help with a shell script, in which case we need to see the script).

Comment: @KeithThompson I've edited my question, hope it helps. I've seen something many years ago that has to do with specifying an index on some value but i've spent hours searching and nothing...

Comment: Found the answer after hours of research. If it helps anybody, i've added the index 0 like this: exec('convert' . ' ' . $file . '[0]  ' . $operator ... I'm not sure why, but it works.

Comment: It is because your source TIFF file contains 2 images, so when you add the index of `0` you just get the first of those two.

Comment: @Marco I've been wrestling with this for HOURS. This answer saved my life. Specifying an index because of how PSDs are formatted? I never would have guessed this. Thank you. Post as the answer and mark solved!